# Kill a process using its PID in ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, process, pid, kill-process

I'm trying to kill a process using its PID after a given period of time, i.e, if the process keeps running for more than 10 minutes, I have to call a method to kill it.

I have two problems: first, i can't manage to kill the process, i'm using:

```
Process.kill('INT', pid)
```

but errors keep popping up like `Bad file descriptor`, or `unsupported name 'SIGQUIT'` when I use the `QUIT` signal instead of `INT`.

Second, how do I make the 10 minutes timer before I call the method to kill the process?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly use  `Process.kill 'SIGKILL', pid` instead (INT is meant to send a ctrl+c and I don't know if its implementation works... https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cc934fc31c221225584d8b33c1f4975fe39c4637/win32/win32.c#L4513 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your timing, you can use a thread:

```
Thread.new do
  sleep 10 * 60
  begin
    Process.kill('QUIT', pid)
  rescue Errno::ESRCH
    # process exited normally
  end
end

_, status = Process.wait2 pid
puts status.exited?
```

I am unsure of why QUIT is not working for you. I could not replicate your error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max, but i still can't use this solution as long as the Process.kill('QUIT', pid) doesn't work, the error says unsupported name `SIGQUIT'.

Comment: So finally i used system("taskkill /im pid /f /t >nul 2>&1") instead of Process.kill('QUIT', pid), and your answer was exactly what i needed.

Comment: You can get a list of what signals are supported with:
puts Signal.list